# Ajax Call to fetch new data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

In the following code i want to add an ajax call in a way that each time, after all images have

been shown, the Ajax will trigger my php to look into the /images folder to see if there any new files.

if there are any new files they should be added and shown in the next cycle.

```
 <html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1000"/> 
<head>
<title>Slideshow</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #slideshow
    #slideshow img { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; }
    #slide {width: 370px; height: 220px; padding: 0;  margin:  0 auto; }

    #myslides {
    width: 370px;
    height: 220px;
    padding: 0;  
    margin:  0 auto;  
} 

#myslides img {  
    padding: 10px;  
    border:  1px solid rgb(100,100,100);  
    background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    top:  0; 
    left: 0 
}

</style>
</head>
<!-- include jQuery library -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slideshow').cycle({
               fx: 'fade',
                speed: 700,
                timeout: 8000
        });
});
</script>

<body>

<div id="slideshow">

<?php

    function returnimages($dirname="./images") {
         $pattern="([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";     
         $files = array();
         if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                if(preg_match($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image 
                    $files[] = $file;
                } 
            }

            closedir($handle);
        }
        //sort($files);         
        natcasesort($files);   

        return($files);
    }

    $images = returnimages(); //will get the array containing the images
    foreach($images as $img)
    {
      echo '<img src="images/' . $img . '" />';
    }
?>

</body>
```

Comment: good. Start reading http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: that wasnt very helpful.

Comment: jQuery Cycle dosen't have a event at end, so it seems it need some kind of hack or extension to make it possible. The ajax call itself is easy enough, just use a load on the slideshow id and on the pageitself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a javascript to your footer that with certain intervalls sends a request for new images:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        setIntervall("fetchImages()", 20000);

        function fetchImages() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "yourImageFetchingScript.php"
            }).done(function(response){
                var curImgCount = $('#slideshow img').length;
                if (response.length > curImgCount) {
                    for (var i = curImgCount; i < response.length; i++) {
                        $('#slideshow').append('<img src="images/' + response[i] + '"');    
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Then *yourImageFetchingScript.php* could just call your returnimages-function and json-encode the result:

```
$images = returnimages();
echo json_encode($images);
```

Check out jQuery's [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

Comment: Oppps... missed your cycle there. Use some even triggered by the cycling to call the fetchImage instead of the setIntervall-function.